# php array_unique() returns duplicate

Tags: php, array-unique

I have some code running and it's been working fine BUT the site in question has started producing a duplicate when the value in an array is "morphsuite"

The code:

```
if(isset($sort2))
  {
   $sort2 = array_unique($sort2);
   foreach($sort2 as $value)
       {
        $f_dress .= '<li><a href="../shop/shop.php?cat=2&amp;sub='.$value.'">'.$value.'</a></li>';
       }
  }
  else{
      $f_dress = '';
      }
```

All the other enteries pull from the DB are OK but getting a double when the value is "morphsuit"

Anyone know why?

Comment: check the length of your "duplicate" morphsuits.  There might be a space on the end of one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values aren't exactly the same - the most likely cause is that there's some kind of non-printable embedded into one or the other (or both); things like whitespace, in-line HTML, or control characters.

Try running var_dump() on the values and pay attention to the length portion of the output when it says something like string(9) "morphsuit" vs. string(2031) "morphsuit" (I invented the number there, but you get the idea).

Comment: Thanks.. don't know what the problem was.(must have been a white space) just gone through the db and copied and pasted "Morphsuits" in to all 6 entries and that seemed to do the trick. First update the client made too :-)